# How many rows inserted not rows executed

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

How can I see how many rows were actually inserted?

```
engine_str = 'mysql+mysqlconnector://root:mypass@localhost/mydb'
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(engine_str, echo=False, encoding='utf-8')
connection = engine.connect()
query = "INSERT INTO TEST(a,b,c)VALUES(1,2,3) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE B = VALUES(B), C = VALUES(C)"
try:
    connection.execute(query)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

SQLALCHEMY just prints out this ID.

```
<sqlalchemy.engine.result.ResultProxy object at 0x0000000007769E80>
```

P.S This question is about rows insertion not row execution. So if you use rowcount it will show the number of times the query has been executed.

Rephrasing my question: Is there any way to see how many records were inserted vs updated? Ideally, I would like to know those primary keys which were updated.

Comment: @Barmar If duplicate is found it doesn't inserts the value. I want to know how many values are inserted. Thank you.

Comment: Isn't it the same thing? I can't really say what your phrases mean, there's no such thing as "row execution".

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: May be I am trying to ask, if there is a way to see which and how many records were actually updated. Rephrased my question.

Answer (score 7):

`ResultProxy.rowcount` will show you the number of rows affected by the query.

For example:

```
>> r1 = connection.execute("INSERT INTO table (id, food, is_tasty) VALUES (1, 'apple', 't'), (2, 'broccoli', 'f'), (3, 'celery', 'f')")
>> print r1.rowcount
3
```

This works for other queries as well:

```
>> r2 = connection.execute("UPDATE table SET is_tasty = 't' WHERE is_tasty = 'f'")
>> print r2.rowcount
2

>> r3 = connection.execute("DELETE FROM table WHERE food = 'celery'")
>> print r3.rowcount
1

>> r4 = connection.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
>> print r4.rowcount
2
```

Comment: Row count gives how many times query has been executed not the record inserted. I ran it for the first time it gave out 96 for 96 rows which were inserted. Second time it should give 0 because the data was not inserted due to duplicate key. But it stills showed 96.


`records_inserted = 0

    try:
        r2 = connection.execute(query)
        rows_inserted += r2.rowcount
`

Comment: @r0xette You have `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` so if you insert the same set a second time, all the existing records are replaced. The counter is correct.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev That is what I thought. Thanks for confirming it. Now is there any way I can find the count of those records only which are inserted vs updated?

Comment: @r0xette there isn't any specialized internal counter because this is not a common task. You can compare `COUNT(*)` before and after the command, wrapping it into a transaction. Alternatively, if you use `INSERT` in a form that doesn't cause updates, the only way it would be able to "affect" rows is to insert them, so `rowcount` would be what you want.

Comment: rowcount gives you number of rows matched, not necessarily updated